# Apache POI insert column values into ArrayList<String[]>

Tags: java, excel, arraylist, apache-poi

I need help inserting column values into an `ArrayList<String[]>` structure. If I have this Excel sheet:

[image]

I use two data structures. One `HashMap` for the column names and the `ArrayList<String[]>` for the values. I am able to get the column names just fine but can't figure out how to get the values.

Here's my code:

```
Map<String, Integer> columnNames = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
List<String[]> values = new ArrayList<String[]>();
DataFormatter dataFormat = new DataFormatter();
FormulaEvaluator eval = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();

Row row;
int valueIndex = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
    row = (Row) sheet.getRow(i);

    Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();

    // Read each cell in the row
    for(int j = 0; cells.hasNext(); j++) {
        Cell cell = cells.next();

        // Column Headers
        if(cell.getRowIndex() == 0) {
            eval.evaluate(cell);
            String cellVal = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell, eval);
            columnNames.put(cellVal, j);

        // Column values
        } else {
            eval.evaluate(cell);
            String cellVal = dataFormat.formatCellValue(cell, eval);

            // What do I write here?
            values.add(j, //cellVal_at_valueIndex);
        }
    }

    // Go to next index for values (down 1 row)
    valueIndex++;
}
```

I'm not sure how to add the value to the `ArrayList` on this line:

```
values.add(j, //cellVal_at_valueIndex);
```

If I just put `cellVal` then it won't correlate to the column mappings in the `HashMap` correctly. Bascially, I want it to look like this:

```
HashMap:                      ArrayList:
------------------            --------------------
Key     |    Value            String    |    Index         
------------------            --------------------
id           0                1              0
number       1                2              1
time         2                ...            ...
```

From here, I can do something like `values.get(columnNames.get("id"))[valueIndex];`

I'm doing it like this because there can be any number of columns and values for each. It will also be easier to get a value from a certain column using a get method.

How can I add the values in the String array? I feel like I'm missing something simple. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) 
{
    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    values.add(cell.getNumericCellValue());
} 
else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) 
{
    System.out.print(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
    values.add(cell.getRichStringCellValue());
} 
else if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN) 
{
    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
    values.add(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
}
```

For more info take a look at [Getting the cell contents](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CellContents) link.